# ODBC Connection Dynamic From Clause

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, visual-foxpro, pass-through

```
ODBC;DSN=Test;UID=;PWD=;SourceDB=\\server\folder\Test\prime.dbc;SourceType=DBC;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;
```

Then the functional static query that uses that connection.  There are 5 tables in prime.dbc.

```
Select field1, field2 field3
From Table1
```

Now based on the function below I want to feed funTestShipUic to the FROM clause instead of the static Table1.

```
Public Function funTestShipUic() As String

   funTestShipUic = lngTestShipUic

End Function
```

I have tried ...

```
Select field1, field2 field3
From funTestShipUic()
```

But I get ODBC--call failed.  ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver Invalided subscript reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

You can build dynamic SQL in VBA with string concatenation, like this:

```
strSql = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM " & myFunctionThatReturnsATableName()
Set myRecordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
```

You can also assign that SQL to an existing query, including PassThrough queries.

```
DB.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL = strSql
```

Comment: I understand everything you are saying.  I have used the same method successfully elsewhere in the database but only with MS tables.  The catch seems to be the pass-thru query via the FoxPro ODBC.  This whole process is importing the data from a FoxPro DB to a Access DB.  The "Test" folder in the FoxPro DB can have any one of 5 collections and therefor will fail with static table names.  I am looking now at how to do a passthru in VBA.

Comment: @Kaw4Life: It's the same method. Set up your PassThrough query with the ODBC connection, then you can do `DB.QueryDefs("myPassThroughQuery").SQL = strSql` in VBA. But you cannot use functions in PassThrough queries, the SQL is sent to the DB server as is.

Comment: I've got something working.  Once refined/complete I will post for others to use, God forbid they need to.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use ODBC with VFP, unless you are using VFP6 and earlier or ADS server. Instead simply use OLEDB (VFPOLEDB). Then you can pass your function's result as a parameter. ie:

```
Select field1, field2 field3 From (?)
```

and add funTestShipUic() to parameters collection. If you used ODBC then in a passthrough query it would be like:

```
Select field1, field2 field3 From (?funTestShipUic())
```

Parameters are handled by the drivers and SQL is not sent to the server as is.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I have a solution in place with consideration to all facets of the given the environment.